# Python(3.3) map function behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import glob,os

os.chdir("C:\\path")
```

after this if I execute a line

```
map(lambda y:os.remove(y),filter(lambda x:os.path.getsize(x)==0,glob.glob('*')))
```

it does not remove the files of size zero

But if I do this

```
list(map(lambda y:os.remove(y),filter(lambda x:os.path.getsize(x)==0,glob.glob('*'))))
```

it removes the files.
How does this actually work?

Comment: Creating unwanted lists for side-effects is confusing and a bad ideas.  Use straightforward code like `for file in filter(...): os.remove(file)` that says and does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python3 the `map` function returns a `map object` (instead of a list in Python2).
This is designed for [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), which means the value was not evaluated before used. And `list` evaluates it.

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) in Python 3.x returns an iterator. The function passed to the `map` is not called until the iterator is iterated.

[`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) consumes the iterator; causing the function to be called.